# Using z-index and position values to align divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a banner which spans the page width. A centered container measuring 1130px within this region holds five blocks of color at 20% of the container. Behind this container should be two divs at 50% each - one containing the first color swatch and the other containing the last to create a seamless palette but maintain the same width.

The issue I'm having at the minute is that the `.modal-container` which holds the five colour blocks will not display on top of the two background blocks `.modal-left` and `.modal-right`. I've tried tinkering with the z-index values of all three classes to no avail. `position: absolute` isn't an option either as this knocks the `margin: 0 auto` alignment off. Any ideas?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cq27S/)

[The effect I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPJ39.png)

Comment: I am a bit confused about the question, what are you achieving?

Comment: @AliGajani I've rewritten the OP to better detail the issue.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

*I just got really carried away and did a total overhaul on that code.  I'M SORRY I COULDN'T HELP MYSELF LOL*

### [New and improved ya dig.](http://jsfiddle.net/lacoolj/fay7t/)

---

Your HTML simply needed some re-arranging.  The `inner` div placed above the other two fixed it right up.

### CSS (updated):

```
.modal {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #3e454c 50%, #ff7f66 50%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #3e454c 50%, #ff7f66 50%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #3e454c 50%, #ff7f66 50%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #3e454c 50%, #ff7f66 50%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3e454c 50%, #ff7f66 50%);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 54px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1130px;
}
.modal-inner {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1130px;
}
.modal-block {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 27px;
}
.una {
    background: #3e454c;
    background: rgba(62, 69, 76, .5);
}
.dos {
    background: #2185c5;
    background: rgba(33, 133, 197, .5);
}
.tres {
    background: #7ecefd;
    background: rgba(126, 206, 253, .5);
}
.cuatro {
    background: #fff6e5;
    background: rgba(255, 246, 229, .5);
}
.cinco {
    background: #ff7f66;
    background: rgba(255, 127, 102, .5);
}
```

### HTML (less is more :) ):

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-inner">
        <div class="modal-block una"></div>
        <div class="modal-block dos"></div>
        <div class="modal-block tres"></div>
        <div class="modal-block cuatro"></div>
        <div class="modal-block cinco"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the response however the `.modal-inner` container still doesn't appear on top of the background blocks :S?

Comment: When you say 'on top of' the background blocks, do you mean vertical position or overlapping depth?  If you mean depth, then I'll fix it so it layers over them.

Comment: @user3149629 I just updated it quite radically.  I made the bottom layer tall enough just so you could see the contrast between the two and see that they were overlapping.  Just put the two `height`s back to `6px` that you had before if you want it how it was.  Hope this is closer to your expectations :)

Answer (score -1):

See demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/cq27S/3/

First, re-arrange your divs to put the 50/50 underneath
Second, and most importantly, add this to .modal-inner 
I believe this is better solution than setting position/margins

```
 display:block;
```

Comment: All `div`s begin as `block` display elements.  Also, the z-indexes he had on there are still there and very unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mention most importantly to re-arrange the divs.